# Python - Parallelisation of a loop

Tags: python, parallel-processing, joblib

I am trying to parallelize a loop that is very costly.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np

class em:

    def __init__(self, k, x, iterations):

        self.k = k
        self.x = x
        self.iterations = iterations

        self.n = self.x.shape[0]
        self.pi = np.array([1 / self.k for _ in range(self.k)])
        self.z = np.ndarray(shape=(self.k, self.n))

    def fit(self):

        for i in range(self.iterations):
            print('iteration', i)
            self.expectation_step()
            self.maximization_step()

    def expectation_step(self):
        # update z
        pass

    def maximization_step(self):
        # update pi and parameters
        pass

class bmm_em(em):

    def __init__(self, k, x, iterations=1000, d=784):

        super().__init__(k, x, iterations)
        self.d = d

        self.mu = np.random.rand(self.k, self.d)

        for m in range(self.k):

            normalization_factor = 0.0
            for i in range(self.d):
                self.mu[m,i] = np.random.random() * 0.5 + 0.25
                normalization_factor += self.mu[m, i]
            for i in range(self.d):
                self.mu[m,i] /= normalization_factor

    def expectation_step(self):

        prod = np.zeros(self.k)

        for n in range(self.n):
            for m in range(self.k):
                t = self.pi[m]
                t *= np.prod(np.power(self.mu[m], self.x[n]))
                t *= np.prod(np.power((1.0 - self.mu[m]), (1.0 - self.x[n])))
                prod[m] = t

        s = sum(prod)
        for n in range(self.n):
            for m in range(self.k):
                if s > 0.0:
                    self.z[m,n] = prod[m] / s
                else:
                    self.z[m,n] = prod[m] / float(self.k)

    def maximization_step(self):

        for m in range(self.k):
            n_m = np.sum(self.z[m])
            self.pi[m] = n_m / self.n # update pi
            self.mu[m] = 0
            for i in range(self.n):
                self.mu[m] += self.z[m,i] * self.x[i].T
            self.mu[m] /= n_m
```

The very costly part is the first loop in `bmm_em.expectation_step`.

I looked at the **joblib** module but couldn't figure out how I can rewrite my code to make it work.

Can anyone give me a hint? :)

Comment: The basic rule of pure-Python performance is: avoid loops. Thus you could a) vectorize the loop using NumPy functions, e.g. `np.dot` (this might require switching to logarithms) b) re-write it in Cython. 

I think `joblib` won't do much with the current version of the code.

Comment: It looks like you're implementing a mixture of Bernoulli distributions, so both the M- and E- steps should be vectorizable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **@Sergei** noted, the use of numpy is preferred here.

Here is what my code became, it's way way faster

```
def _log_support(self):

    pi = self.pi; mu = self.mu

    log_support = np.ndarray(shape=(self.k, self.n))

    for k in range(self.k):
        log_support[k, :] = np.log(pi[k]) \
            + np.sum(self.x * np.log(mu[k, :].clip(min=1e-20)), 1) \
            + np.sum(self.xc * np.log((1 - mu[k, :]).clip(min=1e-20)), 1)

    return log_support

def expectation_step(self, log_support):

    log_normalisation = np.logaddexp.reduce(log_support, axis=0)
    log_responsibilities = log_support - log_normalisation

    self.z = np.exp(log_responsibilities)
```